# query to remove groups of duplicates

Tags: mysql

We have a db with 100s of millions of records. Its timestamped data from door sensors that read 0/1. Not very complex.

The issue comes from the fact that the sensors also have a 'heartbeat'. They output repeats of whichever state they are in. This can repeat anywhere from 1 to n times.

```
eg: 0101111101010000
```

I need to remove the heartbeats and keep the open/close pairs. So this data would become:

```
010101010
```

I can do this in Matlab (not practical for this situation ) and I can do it in Perl. Is there a way to do it via a query (or queries) and would this be any faster than Perl (or equivalent)?

EDIT: Some more specifics: This is row data. A given row is "sequence", "sensor id", "time stamp", "code". It's this "code" value that repeats from row to row.

Comment: Is that as 1 string in a column, or per-state records?

Comment: Its a column. Each row has one 'code'. The repeats occur in sequential columns for a given sensor.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on how the data is put together. Can you give us some structure?

Comment: OK, do you want to save the _first_ of a code by timestamp, the _last_ of a code-run by timestamp, or doesn't that matter?

Comment: I need to remove the duplications. So if (row-wise) a series is 01010010111 I need to end up with 01010101. Remove one 'zero' and two 'ones'.

Comment: I still wonder whether [I understand this correctly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77c23/1/0)?

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723495/group-only-the-adjacent-rows

Comment: @Wrikken : 1 ) that's a nifty site. 2 ) Im looking into your answer too.

Comment: It is indeed, especially for questions such as on SO. My answer could work, _but_ it would require 2 self joins... that may be heavy on a table of _"100s of millions of records. "_....

Comment: true. Im starting to think this needs to happen post-query. Alas.

Comment: But, on the other hand, if you want to actually _remove_ the data it is a good run-once cleanup, add a pre-insert trigger to prevent new clashes and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a [*user-defined function*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) in MySQL which loops, replacing each duplicate number in the string one value at a time (e.g. `0000 -> 000 -> 00 -> 0`) until the number is unique:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION removeDuplicates (str VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE prevVal VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE curVal VARCHAR(255);
    SET curVal = str;

    REPEAT
        SET prevVal = curVal;
        SET curVal = REPLACE(REPLACE(prevVal, '11', '1'), '00', '0');
    UNTIL prevVal = curVal
    END REPEAT;

    RETURN curVal;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can use this function anywhere in your query. For example:

```
SELECT removeDuplicates(your_column) FROM your_table
```

Example outputs:

```
SELECT removeDuplicates('0101111101010000');
---> 010101010

SELECT removeDuplicates('011100000111100101010');
---> 01010101010

SELECT removeDuplicates('111010001011101110100010101');
---> 10101010101010101

SELECT removeDuplicates('111111111111111111111');
---> 1

SELECT removeDuplicates('000000000000000000000');
---> 0

SELECT removeDuplicates('11');
---> 1

SELECT removeDuplicates('00');
---> 0

SELECT removeDuplicates('1');
---> 1

SELECT removeDuplicates('0');
---> 0
```

Comment: These are row-wise repeats. Each row has one code "0" or "1". The repeats occur from row to row rather than a sequence in one row.

Comment: @ethrbunny, oh, I see. The way you formatted your question made it seem like it was a string in a column(but I see that you have since edited your question). Well in that case, I believe Wrikken already has your answer, but I will leave this up here for anyone wanting to know how to remove duplicates from a ***string***.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but here's my try

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('0101111101010000', '111', '1'), '11', '1'),'11','1'),'000','0'),'00','0'),'00','0');
```